# Using commercialhaskell/stack with a proxy

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to use [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) behind a corporate proxy. Issuing the `stack new` command returns:

```
InvalidProxyEnvironmentVariable "http_proxy" "http://username:password@host:port/"
```

I have `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `ftp_proxy` defined in my `.bashrc`, as well as their equivalents in all caps (e.g. `HTTP_PROXY`). Removing or altering those will break stuff elsewhere.

The stack repo doesn't seem to have proxy behaviour documented yet, which is understandable since it was only recently released. Does anyone know if using stack behind a proxy is even possible at the moment? If so, how?

Comment: Actually, that pull request only added support for authentication values in the request URL itself, not in talking with the proxy. [This is the relevant line.](https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/blob/dc981b9fde57d77ccecf0171a96fb92c5cb5712f/http-client/Network/HTTP/Client/Manager.hs#L503) This is worth opening as an http-client issue

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman okay thanks, I'll do it when I get home.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a limitation of http-client, which has now [been reported](https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/issues/129) and [resolved](https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/commit/f6397dcc2a7472b34c986ab54ac854cb3fb08fa5). This change will get released to Hackage in the next few days, and then hopefully the next official build of stack will include the change. If you're adventurous, you can build the [http-proxy-auth branch](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/tree/http-proxy-auth), which includes this fix pre-release.

Comment: http-client with proxy auth fix has been released to the Hackage. please, release stack with it, we can not use stack behind corporate proxy :-/

Comment: I am also using a proxy and stack doesn't work for me. I get a `ProxyConnectException`, with `statusMessage = \"Proxy Authentication Required\"`. I have the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables set up, and interacting with github works, but stack fails.